# How to bind data like history to a scroll in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Hi all i have table which looks likes this

```
                       BugHistory
         -------------------------------------
         BugHIstoryId|BugID|FixedBy|AssignedTo|Resolution
             1       | 4   |Null   |Anil      |There Is a Bug
             2       | 4   |Anil   |Raghu     |Checked its not a bug
             3       | 4   |Null   |Anil      |That is a bug sending You Reference
             4       | 5   |       |Sravan    |
```

i want to bind this data to like chat History With name and Resolution i want to show this like chat ..it should have a scroll so how how can i do this any ideas please..i googled about how to do this didnt get any thing related to this

```
      It Should look like this

        Anil:Resolution
        Raghu:Resolution
        Anil:Resolution
```

can any one help me how to solve this or any ideas please,the scroll should not be shown foe new user if there is no resolution or new BUGID is asssigned to new user at first when there is history build then the scroll should be populated

Comment: I did not get your question. Is it: You have a large list of items and you want to display them all. However, as the list is large, you want that scrollbar will appear?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with the serverside. Its all about style. Here is what your view should be like. The height set to outer div is for demo purpose. But `overflow-y: auto` is what you need to do.

Make sure you do not use inline styles like in the example bellow.

```
@model IEnumerable<BugHistory>
<div style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div>
        @foreach(var item in Model) {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedTo)
            @: :
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Resolution)
            <br />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```